# KeyError: “word 'word' not in vocabulary” in word2vec

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I am using `word2vec`, wiki corpus I trained, what can I do if the word I input not in vocabulary in `word2vec`?

**Test it a bit:**

```
model = word2vec.Word2Vec.load('model/' + 'wiki_chinese_word2vec.model')    
model['boom']
```

**Error:**

> KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)

Comment: Check `if 'boom' in model` before retrieving it.

Comment: It's jus a sample, I check the word I want in the wiki's corpus, but not in the model.

Answer (score 3):

Use `try` & `except` to handle exceptions in Python. `try` block executes normally. If any exception or error occurs then `except` block will be executed.

```
try:
        c = model['boom']
except KeyError:
        print "not in vocabulary"
        c = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

when you say

> what can I do if the word I input not in vocabulary in word2vec

I interpret it two ways

1) How to escape this exception: You can use try , catch

2) How to handle this exception: retrain the model with the missing words accommodated again.You have an option to incrementally train the model , with new corpus ,in word2vec, please go through the gensim tutorial in detail.

I presume that "boom" is not available in the corpus that you have passed, hence the trouble