# word2vec - KeyError: "word X not in vocabulary"

Tags: gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

Using the `Word2Vec` implementation of the module `gensim` in order to construct word embeddings for the sentences I do have in a plain text file. Despite the word `happy` is defined in the vocabulary, getting the error `KeyError: "word 'happy' not in vocabulary"`. Tried to apply the given the answers to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133844/keyerror-word-word-not-in-vocabulary-in-word2vec), but did not work. Hence, posted my own question.

Here is the code:

```
try:
    data = []
    with open(TXT_PATH, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as txt_file:
        for line in txt_file:
            for part in line.split(' '):
                data.append(part.strip())

    # When I debug, both of the words 'happy' and 'birthday' exist in the variable 'data'
    word2vec = Word2Vec(data, min_count=5, size=10000, window=5, workers=4)

    # Print result
    word_1 = 'happy'
    word_2 = 'birthday'
    print(f'Similarity between {word_1} and {word_2} thru word2vec: {word2vec.similarity(word_1, word_2)}')
except Exception as err:
    print(f'An error happened! Detail: {str(err)}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a "not in vocabulary" error like this from `Word2Vec`, you can trust it: `'happy'` really isn't in the model.

Even if your visual check shows `'happy'` inside your file, a few reasons why it might not wind up inside the model include:

- it doesn't occur at least `min_count=5` times
- the `data` format isn't correct for `Word2Vec`, so it's not seeing the words you expect it to see.

Looking at how `data` is prepared by your code, it looks like a giant list of all words in your file. `Word2Vec` instead expects a sequence that has, as each item, a list-of-words for that one text. So: not a list-of-words, but a list where each item is a list-of-words.

If you've supplied...

```py
[
  'happy',
  'birthday',
]
```

...instead of the expected...

```py
[
  ['happy', 'birthday',],
]
```

...those single-word-strings will be seen a lists-of-characters, so `Word2Vec` will think you want to learn word-vectors for a bunch of one-character words. You can check if this has affected your model by seeing if the vocabulary size seems small (`len(model.wv)`) or if a sample of learned-words is only single-character words ('model.wv.index2entity[:10]`).

If you supply a word in the right format, at least `min_count` times, as part of the training-data, it will wind up with a vector in the model.

(Separately: `size=10000` is a choice way outside the usual range of 100-400. I've never seen a project using such high-dimensionality for word-vectors, and it would only be theoretically justifiable if you had a massively-large vocabulary and training-set. Oversized vectors with smaller vocabularies/data are likely to create uselessly overfit results.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. The modifications I have done through your feedback worked like a charm. When I decreased the `size` to 100, and 400, got the `similarity score` of 0.795, and 0.7177, respectively which was 0.928 before.